# How can I specify my own registry for Quarkus native image build?

Tags: quarkus, podman

I want to build my native image, but don't have GraalVM installed.

So, according to the documentation, this is what I do:

```
mvn clean package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true
```

We have Nexus acting as Image registry, and `/etc/containers/registries.conf` points to it:

```
[registries.search]
registries = [ 'our.nexus' ]
```

However, I still see Podman going directly onto the Internet, which makes the build terribly slow. We have a Firewall that analyzes anything that's downloaded.

```
 Trying to pull quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:22.0-java11...
 Getting image source signatures
 Copying blob 4f8ddd7f5a75 done
 Copying blob 54e56e6f8572 done
 Copying blob c7a9994ad8bb [--------------------------------------] 497.9KiB / 486.2MiB
```

And then I wait and wait and wait...

Why is Podman not using our registry? What Quarkus configuration do I need?

Comment: did you login to this registry using podman login?

Comment: How are you doing image pull exactly? command/docker file?

Comment: He's not doing pull as it's quarkus calling podman from maven, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation you have to use this param to do the job

```yaml
-Dquarkus.native.builder-image=yourOwnRegistry/image:version
```

I also used a lot jib which has distincts params, for example :

```yaml
mvnw clean install -Pnative
      -Dquarkus.jib.base-native-image=quay.io/quarkus/quarkus-micro-image:1.0
      -Dquarkus.container-image.builder=jib
      -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true
      -Dquarkus.container-image.push=true
```

Which I currently use (tested, working on my pc and on gitlab CI)

Relevant [Native building docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/native-reference) and [Jib/Docker/S2i docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/container-image)

Comment: Thanks a lot! After configuring quay.io in Nexus, everything worked.